# Python: every possible subset combination from a list

Tags: python, algorithm, combinations, python-itertools

i have a list:

```
list = ["M","M","M","C","C","C"]
```

i want the output to be

```
out = [["M"],["C"],["M,"C"],["M","M"],["C","C"]]
```

how to do this? Thanks in advance!

I have used this code:

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
stuff = ["M","M","M","C","C","C"]
def all_subsets(ss):
    p = map(lambda x: combinations(ss, x), range(1, 3))
    return p

for subset in all_subsets(stuff):
    print(list(subset))

for subset in all_subsets(stuff):
    print(list(subset))
```

but the output is
[image]

Comment: Check out the `itertools` module.

Comment: why isnt the combination [MMM, CCC] included in the list ?

Comment: i only want combination with 2 element @AbhishekKulkarni

Comment: It looks like you're getting the output you want, you just need to get rid of duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want combinations with 1 and 2 elements then maybe try [itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations):

```py
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> l = ["M", "M", "M", "C", "C", "C"]
>>> combs = set(list(combinations(l, 1)) + list(combinations(l, 2)))
>>> out = list(map(list, combs))
>>> print(out)
[['C', 'C'], ['M', 'M'], ['C'], ['M', 'C'], ['M']]
```